# 3dsmax to Unity export animation

Tags: animation, export, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

I'm having some difficulty exporting animated meshes from 3dsmax to Unity3d.

I've succeeded in getting transform animations to export ok, for instance if something is moving. But animated parameters on something dont seem to export, for instance the height of box.
Here are my fxb export settings
[image]

I'm guessing they are losing this information when they are turned from boxes to meshes and i must bake the animations on manually somehow but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex animation is not supported.
Use bones, skin the mesh and animate that way instead.